# How to access the data of firebase firestore subcollection in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux-firestore

I have to acces my chat app data in my dashboard

[image: my firestore collection]

[image: and I have to go to mudgalgiri@gmail.com]

how can I get the access of that data in firestore and display it into my dashboard

Comment: What about reading the Google Firestore API? https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. What did you already tried?

Comment: i have tried the normal get method to access but there are lots on subcollection and I am not able to access the desired location